# How to use <parent> and <child> component in template recursion in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 components `<parent>` and `<child>`. I want to use them in recursive `<ng-template>`

let say for the sake of simplicity

`<parent>` component will contain `<ul>`

`<child>` component will contain `<li>`

here is what I have referenced  https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72

here is how I have tried

```
<div>
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
    <span *ngFor="let item of list">
     <!--  commented {{item.title}} -->
      <child [item]="item"/>
      <!-- commented <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0"> -->
       <template>
            <parent [item]="item"/>
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
       </template>
      <!-- commented </ul> -->
    </span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
</div>
```

but above code does not work properly

**my expected result should look like below shown, for a parent with 2 childs**

```
<span>
   <parent>
   <child/> // <--  child 1
   <child/> // <-- child 2
</span>
```

**with html it look like below**

```
<span>
   <ul>Parent</ul>
   <li>child 1</li> // <--  child 1
   <li>child 1</li> // <-- child 2
</span>
```

it must follow same nesting with any level.

please help me with a demo from https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72

Please help me thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

main.component.html

```
<div>
  <parent *ngFor="let item of list" [item]="item">
</div>
```

parent.component.html

```
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
<ul>
  <child *ngFor="let child of item.children" [item]="child">
</ul>
```

child.component.html

```
<li>
  <parent [item]="item">
</li>
```

Comment: actually data structure is nested tree not simple one as you thought here is that data structure https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72#file-any-component-ts-L12

Comment: my code works with this data structure

Comment: the recursion will build components as every parent renders child components then every child renders nested parent